# What are the negative points of creating dlls?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, windows-services

Let's think I'm writing a windows service and a win32 application in visual c++. These both do the same function except the service does it again and again. Both the applications need modules which are separate DLLs. 
I have few questions,

1. Is it a good practice to include overlapping (used in both app and service) code in DLLs?
2. What are the defects may occur when creating separate DLLs for applications (Those DLLs may include exported Classes and exported global functions)?
3. What is the difference when implementing a class inside an application and implementing it in a separate DLL and use it in the application?

P.S. Assuming both the service and the application are mutually exclusive in the timeline (Runs one at a time).

Comment: The difference between an EXE and a DLL is one flag in the PE optional headers. What are you really interested in?

Comment: The only significant benefit of sharing a DLL between two executables is that you save a bit of disk space.  Perhaps memory if both are running at the same time.  Personally, on modern machines, I don't think it worth the effort.

Comment: Sounds like you are adding extra complexity and the potential for DLL hell, for no benefit. Instead of asking a broad and unsuitable question asking for lists of downsides, perhaps you ought to ask yourself what benefits you will gain by taking this route. Ask yourself what is wrong with making two executables that are built from the same source? Or even a single executable that switches behaviour based on command line arguments.

Comment: @IInspectable I was expecting the programming benefits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Helpful answer. I was thinking creating a bundle of reusable modules would help functioning both applications. Am I wrong? or is it not a concern?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I wasn't targeting to save disk space or memory but to save programming time and reduce code. I'm sorry that the question itself doesn't explain my concerns.

Comment: There are no programming benefits. It is more work, no matter how you look at it: It's more work to set up projects and dependencies, more work to export/import symbols, more work when passing CRT resources across DLL boundaries. It can be helpful in structuring your project, by splitting up responsibilities into separate modules. This makes enables code reuse easier, and (possibly) allows for testing modules in isolation. From the sound of it, though, you are probably overengineering this.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I'm satisfied. :)

Comment: The two executables can share some of the same source code without using a DLL!  That's a completely different question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for the info. I will check. :)